# Glide Android executorService The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos, executorservice

Buenas estoy teniendo siempre el problema al levantar la aplicación

Estoy agregando en mi activity main ExecutorsService para poder distribuir la carga con threads. Basicamente cada vez que veo que un método va a realizar una consulta a un servicio o tiene peso lo encapsulo en un handler. Pero siguen apareciendo de estos errores.

```
            ExecutorService executor5 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Handler handler5 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            executor5.execute(() -> {
                handler5.post(() -> {
```

Que me sugieren para solucionarlo:
Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

GRacias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!